# ¿Qué devuelve el operador new, cuándo no hay espacio en memoria disponible en C++?

Tags: c++

he encontrado una excepción como esta:

```
try{
//codigo
}catch (std::bad_alloc)
{

}
```

Comment: el operador new lanza la exception `std::bad_alloc` cuando no hay memoria suficiente para allocar el pedido. no devuelve nada. lanza la execption. ¿esa es la pregunta?

Comment: si en parte, pero ¿como lanzar la excepción correctamente?

Comment: te refieres para testear el codigo?

Comment: si así es, la sintaxis del error

Comment: disculpa, no entindo a que te refiers con "la sintaxis del error" puedes elaborar que intentas lograr?

Comment: una disculpa, la sintaxis con la que indicaré el error en caso de que no haya memoria disponible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuando no puede reservar la memoria pedida `new` no devuelve nada; lanza una excepción `std::bad_alloc`, la cual se captura como cualquier otra excepción.

```
int main(void) {
  try {
    char* p = new char[1024L*1024L*1024L*1024L*1024L];
    std::cout << "Reserva con exito" << std::endl;
    delete[] p;
  }
  catch ( std::bad_alloc& ex ) {
    std::cout << "No hay memoria suficiente" << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

El código anterior (suponiendo que no tengas un petabyte de memoria disponible) producirá una excepción. Con lo que al ejecutarlo el resultado será :

> jose2@HP-Negro:~/t$ g++ -o nomem nomem.cpp
>   jose2@HP-Negro:~/t$ ./nomem
>   No hay memoria suficiente

Si no quieres que se produzca la excepción puedes usar `std::nothrow`. En tal caso `new` devolverá `NULL` si no hay memoria suficiente.

```
#include <iostream>
int main(void) {
  char* p = new (std::nothrow) char[1024L*1024L*1024L*1024L*1024L];
  if ( p != NULL ) {
    std::cout << "Reserva con exito" << std::endl;
    delete []p;
  }
  else
    std::cout << "No hay memoria suficiente" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: El programa ¿sabe de antemano cuánta memoria hay disponible? o de lo contrario, ¿Va llenando de a poco la memoria hasta agotarse? Si es lo segundo entonces intentar eso sería peligroso.

Comment: En Linux, usando la llamada al sistema `brk()` aumenta la memoria reservada para un programa. Si `brk()` tiene exito los `new` posteriores que no excedan de esta memoria tendrán éxito seguro. En otros sistemas hay mecanismos similares.

Comment: muchas gracias :)